# Jstree - How to properly place on template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jstree

How to center jsTree on template properly? I tried to use just <center>, but I got something like this
[image]

As the image shows it's difficult to see which node is child/parent.
I like how it's made on https://www.jstree.com/ (squares on the right).

Template code (I don't think if it's needed):

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>XLS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>

<body onload="PathInit()">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <center>
        <br><b>Select a directory.<br></b></center><br><br>
    <script>
        function PathInit() {
            $.get("/xls/path/", {
                path: ""
            });
        }

    </script>
    <center>
        <div id="container" name="container">
            //Way to many
            <ul>'s and
                <li>'s
        </div>
        <script>
            function myf(a) {
                return a.instance.get_selected(true)[0].text;
            }
            var tree = $('#container')
                .jstree();
            $('#container')
                .on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) {
                    var elo = window.myf(data);
                    console.log(elo);
                    $.get("/xls/path/", {
                        path: elo
                    });
                });

        </script>


        <center><br>
            <form method="post">

                <br><br><b>Select source language:
                    <br>
                    <select name="source" id="source" option selected>
                        {% for o in data %}
                        <option value="{{o.name}}">{{o.full}}</option>

                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                    <br>
                    <br>Select destionation languages:<br></b>
                (hold ctrl to add more items)<br>
                <select multiple name="args[]" id="args" size="10">
                    {% for o in data %}
                    <option value="{{o.name}}">{{o.full}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>

                <br><br><br>


                <input type="submit" value="Send"><br><br></form>
            <a href="/index/">Back</a>
        </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without knowing the data used to create the tree, it is hard to point out an issue. If you are not overriding the jstree styles, the problem could be an incorrect structure of data used to create the tree.

Comment: I create html structutre (<ul> <li> ... </li> </ul>) each time url for the template is called (with python, flask). It represents tree of dirs.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the html structure after Python processes your template.

Comment: <ul>

<li>C:\Users\EminEm\Desktop\Program\root\test
<ul>

<li>C:\Users\EminEm\Desktop\Program\root\test\1
<ul>

<li>C:\Users\EminEm\Desktop\Program\root\test\1\base
<ul>

<li>C:\Users\EminEm\Desktop\Program\root\test\1\base\PSD</li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>

Comment: I don't know how high ur awarness of jstree is so: <ul> Defines next deep lvl of tree </ul> <li> Lists node </li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment issues are due to the html center tag which doesn't work well with jsTree's CSS styles. One way to do it is to remove the tree Div from the center tag and align it with some custom CSS.

```
<div id="container" name="container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table">
        //Way to many <ul>'s and <li>'s
</div>
```